# Trying to update multi images. The code below works if I update single image but on two or more images

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I try to do it with the help of Array then it update all the fields in Firestore and I want to update only the particular field only. I have tried many things but I am not able to achieve what I want.Help.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             i =0;

            HashMap<Integer,String> downloadurii = new HashMap<>();

            if(numap.size()!=0){
                for (  i=1;i<=3;i++){
                    if (numap.containsKey(i)){
                         StorageReference fileRefernces = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                                + "." + getFileExtension(Uri.parse(numap.get(i))));



                        fileRefernces.putFile(Uri.parse(numap.get(i))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                fileRefernces .getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                        String url = uri.toString();
                                        //downloadurii.put(i,url);

                                        if(i == 1)
                                        {
                                            HashMap<String,Object> keymap = new HashMap<>();
                                            keymap.put("image1",url);
                                            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("update").document(userid)
                                                    .update(keymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                                    }else {
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }else if(i == 2)
                                        {
                                            HashMap<String,Object> keymap = new HashMap<>();
                                            keymap.put("image2",url);
                                            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("update").document(userid)
                                                    .update(keymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                                    }else {
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }else if (i == 3)
                                        {
                                            HashMap<String,Object> keymap = new HashMap<>();
                                            keymap.put("image3",url);
                                            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("update").document(userid)
                                                    .update(keymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                                    }else {
```

progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: try with retrofit its less complex and easy to use for this

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: it doesn't give any errors, it uploads the new images in the storage but it doesn't save the link in Firestore when I try to update multiple images but it works fine when I just run code for single image.

Comment: I just want update the images fields. For example there are five different images holder and if user update just two images very first time and then come again and delete one of the old image and update/add it again with new images and will able continue it with the image user didn't delete, just trying to achieve this and if  if I try to do it with help of Array then it updates all the fields and start from zero again and delete the old images.

Comment: I still don't understand you use case actually. do you have some images saved in Cloud Storage and their url references are saved in Firestore and you would like to update these references in Firestore when a new image uploaded ?

Comment: hey just wanted share it with you people that I made few changes and code worked somehow. just wanted to thanks you for trying. take care .

Comment: can you post what helped you to resolve this issue here for the community reference?

Comment: sure...........

Comment: hey can you pls check this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896479/not-able-to-store-image-in-firebase-after-cropping-and-compress-image-code]

Answer (score 1):

```
 [[[[[public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
 imageuriOne = data.getData();
  dpOne.setImageURI(imageuriOne);
        numap.put(1,""+imageuriOne);

 }
}
 private void uploadstoarge(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    HashMap<Integer,String> downloadurii = new HashMap<>();
    if(numap.size()!=0){
        for ( int i=1;i<=3;i++){
            if (numap.containsKey(i) == true){
                int j = i;
                StorageReference fileRefernces = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + "." + getFileExtension(Uri.parse(numap.get(i))));

                fileRefernces.putFile(Uri.parse(numap.get(i))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        fileRefernces .getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                String url = uri.toString();
                                uploadfirestore(j,url);


                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                continue;
            }

        }
    }

}

private  void uploadfirestore(int i,String url) {
    HashMap<String,Object> keymap = new HashMap<>();
    keymap.put("image"+i,url);
  
  firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("update").document(userid)
            .update(keymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}]]]]
```

Comment: I had three images to upload so I made a loop according to that and rest is the users choice whether want to upload one at a time or three and then on Button called  uploadstorage() method.